# Google Assistant Oauth Authentication

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-assistant-sdk

I have a question regarding Google's oauth.
I found this module on npmjs.com called "google-assistant" Which allows you to integrate your app with google assistant (eg: answer text queries)
This is the code I got:

```
const path = require('path');
const GoogleAssistant = require('google-assistant');
const config = {
  auth: {
    keyFilePath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client_secret_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'), // x is a place holder for my client_secret json file name
    // where you want the tokens to be saved
    // will create the directory if not already there
    savedTokensPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tokens.json'),
  },
  // this param is optional, but all options will be shown
  conversation: {
```

(rest of the code is just the default example from https://npmjs.com/package/google-assistant/ )
Everytime I try run the code (node test.js) I get 
[AuthError: No access or refresh token found] And when i remove the tokens.js file, It posts a 'link' and i paste it into my browser and it says 'paste this into your app:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
But the question is, Where do i paste it? Thanks

Comment: You have the good JSON file?

Comment: I have both JSON files, client_secret and tokens.json (tokens.json is empty aka only {} )

Comment: Once you copy the link in your browser and authenticate, you should get a token. You should then paste this back into your command line, which should generate the tokens that you need to authorize with the service.

Comment: Oh OK! I'll try that now